# Having trouble running a backup copy of php on Xampp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, backup, customization

I uploaded a php script to a subdomain that I own, for testing and customizing purposes before it goes live (I had planned on moving everything over to the root domain when done).

Someone then suggested that I work on in Xampp instead as it is all locally installed and therefore much faster, etc.

Thing is, I had already customized the script a lot (mostly CSS but also uploaded graphics via the admin panel, etc) while it was up live on the web host, so I would like to run a copy of the most up-to-date version of it in Xampp and continue customizing it from there.

I downloaded a copy of all my files by FTP into htdocs > Test folder.  I also downloaded a copy of the database via phpmyadmin and imported it via phpmyadmin into my localhost.

The big problem I have is when I try to access the scritp via localhost, the url immediately reverts back to the live url. How do I set it to link to the local host copy instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in the html directory?  That or something in your code is about the only thing that would do that.

Comment: Thank you. Your observation led me to dig deeper and although it wasn't the .htaccess file, I found out I had to change the url to 'localhost' in a config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on AbraCadaver's suggestion, I found the answer lied in changing the URL parameters in config.php

Thanks